# how to read a csv file edited from excel in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I tried loading the csv file that has been edited and saved as csv comma delimited. However it's not loading right.

I used the normal pd_read_csv like so.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',quotechar'"')
```

However the file returns back as so:

| productId | items | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange juice 3 | 300ml |
| 2,"lime juice 3,4","300ml" |  |  |
| 3 | grape juice 2 | 300ml |

When I tried opening the file in text it returns as so

```
productId,items,unit
1,orange juice 3,300ml
2,""lime juice 3,4"",300ml
3,grape juice 2, 300ml
```

What format is the above csv? Where there's no , after each item and using double quotes?
How do I read the csv file?

Comment: The solution probably lies in saving the CSV explicitly in a more interpretable format. There are options for this in excel. Also, there's no way what you say the text file contains produced the table you've shown with your given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you got to that file, but it looks broken.

```
productId,items,unit
1,orange juice 3,300ml
2,""lime juice 3,4"",300ml
3,grape juice 2, 300ml
```

If double quotes are your delimiter (`"`), then you should have a single one around your quoted fields.

```
productId,items,unit
1,orange juice 3,300ml
2,"lime juice 3,4",300ml
3,grape juice 2, 300ml
```

Which pandas can load just fine.

```py
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd

dat = BytesIO(b"""\
productId,items,unit
1,orange juice 3,300ml
2,"lime juice 3,4",300ml
3,grape juice 2, 300ml
""")

pd.read_csv(dat) # and you don't need the quotechar kwarg
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, this is a file generated and the user edited the file in excel csv, I don't know why also how the file is that broken. However this is an automated process and therefore I need to handle the process after. Need help, do I do this dat=BytesIO('data.csv') ? is that possible or do i read the file first?

Comment: BytesIO is just a way to put bytes in a file handle, so I didn’t need to write a file. It’s equivalent to open for existing files. Pandas can take a file name directly like you used above, stick to that if you have a file.